# Terraform 443: connect: no route to host

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Does anyone have any idea why I periodically, yet constantly receive the following error when running terraform plan/apply commands against GCP infrastructure?

```
dial tcp [2607:f8b0:4020:807::200a]:443: connect: no route to host
```

It doesn't happen every time and when it does it just picks a handful of random resources to get this error on. Rarely the same resource though. I find myself having to run terraform plan/apply about a dozen times in a row every time before it successfully goes through and it's driving me nuts.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Gary Turner, If your issue is not yet resolved, Can you separate the K8s deployment into a separate Terraform manifest which you applied after updating the **~/.kube/config file**. Check the DNS errors may be due to this file not being current for the new cluster. Also ensure that **endpoint_private_access = true** is set in your cluster resource.

Answer (score 0):

**'No Route to Host'** denotes a network problem, usually one which shows up when the server or host is not responding. This may happen because of network issues or because of an inappropriate setup.

Seems no configuration issue from your side when running terraform plan/apply commands against GCP infrastructure.

Terraform and Google cloud communicate using the route found within your error. You need to fix that external network connectivity issue that is not related  to Terraform and Google Cloud SDK, Then only you're able to use Terraform with remote Google Cloud Platform again.

You can check the entry for your server in the output of "route -n". If there is none, then you also should check for a bigger prefix for the subnet of the server.
If that also is not present, then you should confirm that you have a default route setup.

**443 :Connect : No Route to Host**

Try to run `curl https://<master-ip-address>:<port>`.

If the port is open you should receive a message related to SSL certificate or HTTPS.

Its port is closed (which is probably the issue in your case) - the no route to host message appears.

**Note :** If your port is disabled, follow this document to [enable the port 443](https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/what-is-port-443-and-how-to-enable-it/).

**EDIT :**

Google Service Networking Connection (Official  Troubleshooting document):

1)[On-premises hosts can't communicate with the service producer's network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#on-premv)

2)Please refer to GCP [REST Resource: services.connections](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-networking/reference/rest/v1/services.connections) for more information.

Comment: Understood that this error typically represents a network problem. I'm just not sure why it's happening for only GCP. I run terraform code all day long most days against many different services like PagerDuty, Datadog, AWS, etc. and never have any issues. It's only when I'm running it against GCP infrastructure that I get this error periodically. So I'm not sure if there's something with the terraform provider for the specific version I'm using.

Comment: Please check the edit in answer for official docs for troubleshooting the network issues. Also please refer to this [Github link](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-network) for terraform network version.

Comment: Hi Veera. Yes I took a look at it, but I wasn't able to figure out what's going on. It's very inconsistent and any test I run always works. It's only when I run the entire terraform project where it gets these errors periodically. Eventually I gave up and just started running my terraform code from a VM where I don't hit the issue. I think it's something to do with my Mac, but not sure.